# How to debug laggy, Slowed Down input and feedback on Monterey

Tags: imac, performance, monterey

What tools can I use to debug a performance issue I am having with my 2020 27" 128 GB iMac running Montery?  Besides Activity Monitor because it is just not working... according to Activity Monitor, everything is fine and there is no resource being overused.

I have upgraded to Monterey 12.5 just after launch.  It was fine for a while but now I have laggy input, delayed feedback from video feeds (Zoom/YouTube).  It feels like an old Windows PC that has not had a fresh install of the OS.

I don't want to go and do a full clean install of my system, but rather figure out what is causing the performance issue.

Thanks.

Comment: In Activity Monitor, are you viewing All Processes? The default is just current user.

Comment: Yeah- I switch to All Processes. Thanks tho!